# Issues with mod_rewrite

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with mod_rewrite.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^article/(.+)$ /article.php?article=$1
```

This is my .htaccess. With the first rewrite_rule, I hide the file extensions.
It works without a problem. With the second rule, I like to turn "article.php?article=Example" into "article/Example". But whenever I try to visit the page via "article/Example" I get an 500 Internal Server Error. The first rule works fine and I can also access the page using article.php?article=Example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverse the order of your rules and use `MultiViews` to disable content negotiation:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^article/(.+)$ /article.php?article=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L]
```